# Can a macro name be located and run based on Excel cell contents search

Tags: excel, vba

I need to go to a specific worksheet cell, read it's contents, and search for it in a macro containing multiple subs. When found, need to run the sub with that name.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) I think you may have misunderstood how stackoverflow operates. You may want to see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please post what you have tried so far. Keep these in mind while posting **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable and we will take it from there :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from a cell, you can use `Range.value` Like:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

For the value of `A1`

To run a sub with the same name as the value, you can call it with `Application.Run`:

```
Application.Run Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Import in Sheet1, cell A1 the word **Code** and run **Sub Test()** first:

```
Sub Code()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        .Range("C1").Select
        
    End With
        
End Sub

Sub test()

    Dim str As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        str = .Range("A1").Value
        
    End With
    
    Application.Run str

End Sub
```